# CA Pinning with CryptoAPI

Tags: windows, pki, cryptoapi

I'm validating an SSL server certificate using CryptoAPI (CertGetCertificateChain and CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy specifically).

I would like to limit which CAs I will accept signatures from, aka CA Pinning.

Is there a way to do this shy of having my own code compare the root cert against a list of acceptable certificates?

Comment: Well, I went ahead and did this by checking the last cert on the last chain returned by CertGetCertificateChain to see if it matches a configured list. I'll leave the answer open for a while to see if there is an integrated way (I don't think there is) and if it doesn't get an answer after a while I'll post an example of doing it manually.